# How do I know if my points have been recalc-ed?

Tags: support

I requested a point recalc on stack overflow earlier today by flagging one of my posts and putting a request in the notification and I don't know if it's happened yet. I haven't noticed a drastic change in my points.

Is there any way I can tell?

*As long as this is up can some SO mod recalc for me and let me know? Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any way of being able to tell outside noticing a difference in reputation. That being said, a notice if you have been recalc'd would be incredibly helpful to users unaware of the feature (I think it has been suggested before).

If a mod sees this hopefully they'll respond to you directly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you see your score dip without any notifications, it is likely part of a recalc. Most recalcs end up with a lower rep, so that is the quickest way to tell (although not the most accurate).

I guess the most efficient way would be to ask for a moderator to email you when they actually do the recalc so you can be sure it was actually done.

Comment: Ah, yeah it was a long day and I actually don't know if it dipped or not. Whoops. =x

Answer (score 1):

In this case, 'cos I'm telling you now ;-p

Done. Damage: -521 (I've seen worse...)

Re any delay - we're not always online, but we try to keep the ♦ gaps to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would be pretty big.