# Does flagging a question cost Rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I just flagged a question I asked prior to opening a SO account, requesting that it be merged with my current account.  A few moments later my rep went down by 2, with no downvotes showing up in the tracker.  Is this expected behavior?  I've flagged a question before (for a different reason) and didn't notice this happening.

The question is here, if that's relevant.

[Too Many Left Outer Joins in Entity Framework 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916830/too-many-left-outer-joins-in-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score 7):

No, flagging does not cost you Rep.

<strike>It looks to me like you were downvoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950648/a-design-pattern-for-constructors) and that's why you lost 2 rep.</strike>

**EDIT:** Wait, you *flagged your own question* to have it merged in with your new account. I see. Then you probably triggered a reputation recalc on yourself, either that or it was a byproduct of the merging. See:

[Inconsistent Reputation After Merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67341/inconsistent-reputation-after-merge)

[How do I know if my points have been recalc-ed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16449/how-do-i-know-if-my-points-have-been-recalc-ed)

[How can I request a reputation recalc?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/how-can-i-request-a-reputation-recalc)

Also, I was given the relevant part of a sample merge log [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/520612#520612):

```
520613 15:49:58
Beginning merge into master User 'user4834' (Id=4834) for merge User 'user4890' (Id=4890).
. . .
Recalculating rep - before: 1
Recalculated rep for User.Id = 4834 -> old rep = 1, new rep = 1
```

As you can see, a rep recalc is triggered.

Comment: No - that downvote was days ago, and there's still nothing showing up in the tracker.  Wierd

Comment: OK. Maybe I am misusing the rep graph, please stand by while I recalculate...

Comment: No. I misunderstood your question. :-)

Comment: [See also this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/how-can-i-request-a-reputation-recalc)